# Simulating keypress into an INPUT field (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, dispatchevent

I'd like to simulate a keypress into an INPUT object.

I can't just set the element value because of the way the field is processed.

Looks like the solution has to do with `dispatchEvent` and `KeyboardEvent` - but there are so many variations and most deprecated.

What's the current modern way of sending printable characters to an INPUT field.

Comment: what is it about "the way the field is processed" which means you can't just use `document.getElementById().value`?

Comment: yes - it seems like an Angular web page and it accepts each keypress and does something app specific on the 3rd letter - i.e. it's like those airline flight pages - enter the identifier (SFO) and then it displays the full city name automatically (like a combo-box)...but it's an INPUT element.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190874/3577695)

Answer (score 11):

For modern web development dom editing use the following:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector("input");
inputElement.value = 'newValue';
inputElement.dispatchEvent(
  new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
);
```

With modern websites we now need to notify event handlers that the field has been changed, for all/any state management to recognise change. Previously without dispatching event you are just modifying the value field through the DOM.

Comment: Thanks ! 
Just to mention for anyone stopping by with similar issue: This way was the only way I was able to fill-in the value on input fields of a Vue App. 
Of course, could be only a  particularity in my specific case and of this specific Vue app

Comment: you have no idea you ended my 6 month problem. it works for linkedin automation!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate a `keypress` event you will have to do:

```
var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: "a" });

input.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

As you said, [the `keypress` event is being deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) and it is not guaranteed to work in the future. It is recommended to use `beforeinput` or `keydown` instead.

Even so, the support for `keypress` is still good, as you can see in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Just tried that from the Firefox web console and it didn't take

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you are doing something different? I built [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59zs1jeh/) so you can check it works.

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem clearly. I'm trying to simulate input into the INPUT field. e.g. I'd like to add S-F-O to the input field. I can't assign element.value - see my comment above - doesn't work.

Comment: In the event listener for the input element, i can do `this.value += ev.key` and it saves it - but it's not triggering the processing event that happens when I input the keys using a keyboard.

Comment: Tried out at new version of Firefox, still doesn't work...

Comment: @dashman, did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue on an input field. I can change the inlut value but as soon as I click or sometimes even hover the input field it returns to its previous value.

Comment: no i didn't. these Angular and React web-pages are a scourge to standard web 2.0 development. The UIs look standard but interaction is very nonstandard and opaque - i'm sure by design.

Comment: This has no effect...

Comment: @dashman Thanks to the blessing of chatgpt I managed to dig to a solution for modern framework based websites. Update the value of the input using `inputElement.value = 'new value'` and add afterwards `inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));`. This second line notifies event handlers that the input has been updated.

Comment: I tried this in Firefox, development inspection console and it doesn't work. On the same United flightstatus page, I can enter the flight number but when I press the SEARCH button - it doesn't take. https://www.united.com/en/us